# Zend session expires prematurely in IE

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I am developing one website in php zend framework.

My cookie lifetime is set to 0 so that any session will expire when all browser windows are closed.

It is working fine in mozila firefox and chrome but its not working properly in internet explorer.

Even if i close any window it expires my session and displays the login screen.

Is there any way or setting to solve this ??

Please help me..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have had problems with sessions in IE8... I tried the P3P method below but found that I had to change cookie handing settings to "Accept 3rd party session cookies" in IE for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem only when i have to use iframe in Internet Explorer. The root of the "problem" is caused by P3P: [enter link description here](http://www.w3.org/P3P/).

You can try to add this header to every page:

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```